# Laragon data loss after lite to full update

Tags: sql, database, data-recovery, laragon

I had to update from lite to full and all my sql tables went missing. I read an article which said there would be no such consequences on update but mysql says table does not exist. Is there a way to get the data back. The data is really important to me so any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd guess the data is still there, but your settings aren't complete.

Comment: @jarlh sorry, what do you mean by settings aren't complete? Is there anything i have to look specific into?

Comment: Same issue just lost 100+ databases by updating from laragon 4 to laragon 5 ... can't find any help with this so far .... what a massive kick in the ...